# How to implement 'While' loop in Excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to create a while loop in an excel worksheet? I don't want to use VBA or something, just the excel worksheet.
I am looking for a general solution for something like:

```
condition_met = False
while not condition_met:
    ...
    ...
    if (some_condition):
        condition_met = True
```

Comment: Excel is not made for this kind of programing, you can only use combinations of mathematical functions. You can't do "side-effects" with formulas

Comment: Though assuming you just want to change the value of a cell when other things change, a simple `if` will do the trick. Formulas are reevaluated after any change in data.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot program in Excel that way. That is why you need to use VBA for such (and many more) things.
Looping requires circular referencing which is not allowed in Excel.
What you can do is:
 - use 'IF' statement for your condition.
 - copy the formula in the cells below.
 - check the result for those cells to see if any one of them is 'True'.

Comment: was afraid someone might suggest that. what if there are 1000's of itterations and 'if' checks. does seem a little impractical.

Answer (score 0):

A cell in Excel can contain only a single expression. Other statements like variable declaration or loops are unavailable. You can think of it a as functional language in some way and you have to understand it is different from what you probably know from other languages.

However, it is important to note that when a cell is modified, all cells that depend on it will be updated.

Assuming you have a condition like `A1=2`, the result in your cell (`true` or `false`) will be updated when you change `A1`.

It might be possible to do what you want with the `if` function but please remember that it only outputs a value (either the `value_if_true` or the `value_if_false`). You cannot affect other cells with that. You need to use VBA or the like for that.